# Does Comments/Identifiers can impact on code performance/operability?

Tags: c, linux, comments, driver, identifier

Today i was presented with a wiered fact (or not)

it was said:
"At  it is disallowed to write long, descriptive identifier names, and forbidden to write Comments for `Linux` Drivers written in `ANSI C`."

When i asked "WTF? Why?" i was told it caused performence issues and errors of such...
not many details there.

I am supprised, but have to ask...
Can this be real?
knowing that Comments are stripped by the compilation pre-processor,
and that Identifiers are either way converted to adresses.

so... Can it cause Problems ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, ANSI C is a standard, and a standard is something itself that everyone `must` follow (I mean compiler designers and programmers, if they decide to support it).

ANSI C standard states that exported identifiers (yeah, exported identifiers are stored as symbols in symbols table as is, not just addresses) must not be longer than 6 characters, and non-exported identifiers are ok to be not longer than 31 character.

On commenting. Except some obvious pitfalls like accidental code swallowing by multi-line commenting, I recommend you to read [Coding Style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) article for Kernel developers which explains what kind of comments are not encouraged.

Comment: if i have a LOOOONNG identifier, it will be a compile-time error,
not performance issue or a bug, right?

Comment: @TomerW, Yes, e.g. Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 does not allow identifiers longer than 1023 characters (Error C1064), though that is up to target platform. Note about memory: longer identifier will obviously take more memory to be stored in a symbol table. Embedded systems (where Linux is broadly spread) are very sensitive to resources, so such coding style restrictions are quite clever, even if you won't get compile error on x86 hardware platform.

Comment: well i think this is the most in depth analysis,
One more clearance plz,
C (as i know) use early binding, and the code itself does not necesserily contain or needs the symbol table (which used for debugging), so it is possible to embed the binaries without the symbols, or am i wrong here?

Comment: @TomerW Even if you have early binding, your object files still have symbols table (for linker to work) and linker keeps it around until it puts final address location for a routine. Thus it makes impact on how much resources to be used during compile time. For extremely large projects (like Kernel is) it often happens that a machine lacks RAM to compile it.

Comment: It should be noted that ANSI C is ancient and is obsolete except for maintenance of ancient systems. Modern ISO/IEC C requires that implementations support at least 31 characters in external identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not. Whatever identifier you used in your code, they will be translated to symbols by compiler.

Also, all comments will be ignored by the compilation pre-processor.

The only effect of comments are help you  understand code more quickly .

Comment: This question explicitly asks about ANSI C, which did limit the supported length of external identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

The only performance impact comments can have is during compile time, though I would say it is neglectable, unless you write whole books as comments.
The identifer names are translated to symbols, so there is also, at best, a performance impact at compiletime, which again is neglectable. Identifer names might hit a maximum limit, but to be honest, I never encountered a problem because of to long identifier names.

Answer (score 0):

No, the first step in the compilation is pre-process your source code to remove comments and do other tricks like expanding macros.

Identifiers are often translated into pointers (to symbol table entries).

Comment: External identifiers cannot be represented as small integers. Enough information must be recorded so that the same identifiers in different translation units can be linked to each other, which essentially means recording every significant character in the name.